# How can i pass the "..." param to UIAlertView's "..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, variadic-functions

This is the message in console

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                  message:(NSString *)message
        cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
        otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
if (self = [super initWithTitle:title message:message
                       delegate:delegate
              cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
              otherButtonTitles:XXXX]) {
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: I can not understand your question, can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can't. There is no way to pass the variable arguments. It's a limitation of the C language.

Comment: BTW - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518076/objective-c-invoke-a-method-with-variable-argument-list-ns-requires-nil-termi?lq=1

Comment: I found the another way to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345196/objective-c-passing-around-nil-terminated-argument-lists?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

Insert this before the super call, and use `ap` as the `...` variable argument parameter.

```
va_list ap;
va_start(ap, otherButtonTitles);

// Replace your XXXX with ap

va_end(ap);
```

Comment: @rmaddy [what says it wont work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391780/how-to-pass-variable-arguments-to-another-method) I've done it before.

Comment: Let me clarify. Yes, you can pass `ap` if (and it's a big if), the other method has a parameter of type `va_list` (like in the last method of the answer you linked in your comment). But that's not the question. The question is how to pass the variable arguments from one method using the `...` syntax to another method also using the `...` syntax. That can't be done. You can't pass the `ap` in your answer to a method that has the `...` syntax.