# How to pass variable parameters in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax

this is my methods:

```
- (void)doSomething:(SEL)aSelector andFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ...;
- (void)justFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ...;
- (void)passDouble:(double)aDouble andFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ...;
- (void)passFloat:(float)aFloat andInt:(int)anInt andFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ...;
```

what I want to do is pass the parameters in the my methods (include `format` and `...`) to a method like this:

```
- (void)formatThings:(NSString *)format, ... {
    // analysis var list and print formatted string
}
```

I tried to pass `va_list` to the second method but I got an error.

---

here's a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2391883/2284065

Comment: call 'justFormaThings:' from 'doSomething:' method like [self justFormatThings:MyString];

Comment: It very basic, you should read more about objecive c.
you can call it simply [self justFormatThings:format];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this code is helpful.

```
- (void)doSomething:(SEL)aSelector andFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ... 
{
    if (aSelector != NULL && [self respondsToSelector:aSelector]) 
    {
        [self performSelector:aSelector];
    }

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //store variable argument string in array
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    for (NSString *arg = format; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*))
    {
        [arr addObject:arg];
    }
    va_end(args);
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);

    // call - justFormatThings:
    [self justFormatThings:[arr componentsJoinedByString:@","],nil];
}
- (void)justFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ... 
{    
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //store variable argument string in array
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    for (NSString *arg = format; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*))
    {
        [arr addObject:arg];
    }
    va_end(args);

    NSLog(@"%@",arr);

}
-(void)tempMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Temp Method");
}
```

You can call `doSomething:andFormatThings:` like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self doSomething:@selector(tempMethod) andFormatThings:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",nil];

}
```

Comment: thx a lot. but what if the  parameters contains other types? don't want to analysis it twice.

Comment: In this situation, `doSomething:andFormatThings:` and `justFormatThings:` both methods containing only `NSString` argument.

Comment: You can use `id` type instead of `NSString` in parameter and edit my code in for loop with `id` instead of `NSString` so you can any type of data in argument.

Comment: so after chnage `id` instead of `NSString` you can call function like `[self doSomething:@selector(tempMethod) andFormatThings: @"a",@"b",@4.4,@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@5,nil];`

Comment: i think you got my point... :)

Comment: so is there any solution to pass the whole variables list to another method? I got an error when I tried to pass a `va_list` .

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: You can check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2391883/2284065. This answer is very similar to your situation.

Comment: ok, thank you for help

Comment: your welcome. are you satisfied with my answer then don't forget to accept or up my answer. thanks.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code...

```
- (void)doSomething:(SEL)aSelector andFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ... {
    if (aSelector != NULL && 
        [self respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
        [self performSelector:aSelector];
    }
    // call - justFormatThings:

    [self justFormatThings:anyString];

}

- (void)justFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ... {
    // code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)doSomething:(SEL)aSelector andFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ... {
if (aSelector != NULL && 
    [self respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
    [self performSelector:aSelector];

}
// call - justFormatThings:
  [self justFormatThings:format];
}

- (void)justFormatThings:(NSString *)format, ... {
// code...
   }
```

Comment: thx, but what about other parameters ( `... `)

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify this.

There are multiple ways to pass parameters to from a function to another.

1- Either from method 1 you call the method second like this:

```
[self justFormatThings:@"you string"];
```

this way you function will call the second function whenever you want.

2- You declare a string property in the .h and use it whenever you want in your class.

for example you declare `NSString *myString;` in .h
and then access it and edit/read it from both methods.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i didnt understand can you explain more?